# Bash - Check if file exists when some of the filename is irrelevant

Tags: bash

I want to check if file exists but only checking if some the filename exists

For example in some folder I have these files (Date format: AAAAMMDD):

Rejets_20190112.csv.zip

Rejets_20190312.csv.zip

Rejets_20190314.csv.zip

I want to check if there is a file that begins with Rejet_DAP_201903 exists in that folder. In other word I want to check if Rejet_DAP file with current year and month exist, the day doesn't matter.

Here's what I tried to do in my script:

```
jour=`date +%d`
mois=`date +%m`
annee=`date +%Y`


    FILE="/appli/project/echanges/RTY/receptions/Rejet_${annee}${mois}"_*


    if [[ -e $FILE  ]]
    then
            echo "FILE EXISTS"
    else
            echo "FILE DOES NOT EXIST"

    fi
```

Comment: The wildcard you tried doesn't actually match the files you wanted to find. Maybe use `...${mois}??"_*`

Answer (score 0):

You have the directory path and the file pattern that you are looking for.

The `ls` command can be used to list files based on patterns.
All commands return an integer value after execution. `0` means the execution finished successfully. Any non-zero value means error.

`ls` will return a non-zero value if no files match the pattern.

That return code you can use within the `if` statement.

```
#!/bin/bash

jour=`date +%d`
mois=`date +%m`
annee=`date +%Y`
/appli/project/echanges

dir="/appli/project/echanges/RTY/receptions"
file_prefix="Rejet_DAP_"


if ls $dir/${file_prefix}${annee}${mois}* > /dev/null 2>&1
then
        echo "FILE EXISTS"
else
        echo "FILE DOES NOT EXIST"
fi
```

The `#!/bin/bash` line is called a shebang line and I highly recommend using it in your scripts.

The `> /dev/null 2>&1` is so that you don't get output from the `ls` command and only have your output displayed.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `find` for this

```
$ if [[ `find /appli/project/echanges/RTY/receptions/ -type f |grep -i Rejet_DAP_${annee}${mois}|wc -l` -gt 0 ]] ; then 
 echo "FILE EXISTS"
else
 echo "FILE DOES NOT EXIST"
fi
```